# How can I implement weighted directed graph using vectors in C++?

Tags: vector

I am trying to use the array of 2D vectors to create the adjacency list representation for the directed weighted graph. I am using the  array of 2D vectors so that with the vertex the corresponding weight can be stored. Any better method ?

Comment: directed graph and priority queue are two unrelated concepts. Also your question is way too broad to get concrete answers and will probably get closed

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev : made some changes. Is that ok now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what my typical representation of a weighted graph in `c++` looks like:

```
vector<vector<pair<int, int> > > adj_list;
```

I use a `std::pair` to store edges first element being the destination node of the edge and the second being its weight. A better approach depending on the case may be to use a custom structure for the node. Something like:

```
struct edge {
  int to;
  int weight;
};

....
vector<vector<edge> > adj_list;
```

Comment: thanks,  we could also use vector<pair<int,int>> g[x]  as the array of vectors to represent the adjacency list, right ?